# Why is Springboot server works differently in localhost and heroku host?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to handle error response. When I use local server I can get error message when exception is hit but when I use the same hosted app It shows response with error message which is null "message":""

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that when the excptionerror is thrown the server gets stoped a while and the response error comes empty due to network delay. But for local database there is no delay which leads the server to keep responding no matter which response it has